# Change color of Visual Studio based on project location?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'd like to have some indicator that the projects I'm working with are either in the dev branch or release branch. Is there some way to set the color of something in Visual Studio based on a part of the project path?

I thought the Productivity Power Tools tab color coding would have worked well, except that their Reg Ex option only looks at the tab name, not the whole path.

Comment: Maybe something other than coloration can indicate this? A file which is only present in that branch which has some information about what your working on? If your using subversion/perforce you can easily rename the actual sln and just consolidate the code files.

Comment: VisualSVN has a toolbar that displays your current branch url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed VSCommands 2010 Lite which is free and can put text in the title bar based on the file path of the solution. So for me, I have the paths "**Main\Source\Solution.sln**" and "**Release\[releaseNum]\Solution.sln**" which display in the title bar as "**Solution.sln - Main Source**" and "**Solution.sln - Release [releaseNum]**" repectively.

```
Friendly Name: {solutionName} - {branchName} {version}
Friendly Name - Solution Path Regex: .*\\(?<branchName>.*).*\\(?<version>.*)\\(?<solutionName>.*(?:.sln))
```

Actually I repeat {branchName} {version} multiple times to make it more apparent. This works well enough for my purposes.